# Select from Enum using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, enums

I have two properties in an object, ChannelName and ChannelValue. I have an Enum with a list of channel Id's.

I want to be able to use a Linq query to say, "select the channel value where the channel name = one of the items in the Enum."

I have this so far, but I get the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string'

The code is:

```
 var channels = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ModbusChannels)).ToList();
            var allChannelValues = "";

            foreach (var item in channels)
            {
                allChannelValues = (from x in data where x.ChannelName.Contains(item) select x.ChannelValue);
            }
```

FYI, where 'data' appears in the appears in the query, this is an object that is fully populated.

The Enum has 500 names in it, but here is a shortened version:

```
 public enum ModbusChannels{
        M0,
        M1,
        M2,
        M3,
        M4,
        M5,
        M6,
        M7,
        M8
}
```

Is this the right way to do this and how do I achieve the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Contains` to check if enum values contain the channel name:

```
var channels = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ModbusChannels)).ToList();
var allChannelValues = data.Where(d => channels.Contains(d.ChannelName)).ToList();
```

Comment: You could also use a [`HashSet<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) for `channels` (e.g. `var channels = new HashSet<ModbusChannels>((ModbusChannels[]) Enum.GetNames(typeof(ModbusChannels)));`) to avoid the linear search of a `List`/array.

Answer (score 1):

The way I am reading your question is that you want to see if the string value of the property `ChannelName` exists as a name in the enumeration `ModbusChannels`.

```
List<string> channels = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ModbusChannels)).ToList();
var allChannelValues = data
                   .Where(x => channels.Contains(x.ChannelName))
                   .Select(x => x.ChannelValue)
                   .ToList();
```

This will not work if this string value contains multiple values like a CSV string. In that case it would be more clear if you included sample values.

Comment: That is correct. There about 2,000 channel Id's in the Enum. I want to select the ChannelValue from the 'data' object, if the ChannelName exists in the Enum.

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin - well that should do it then. I am not sure what the `ChannelValue` type is, I had it as the same enum type but that was an assumption.

Comment: I tried it, but I keep getting conversion errors. I used this as offered by Selman below:   var channels = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Channels)).ToList();   
            var allChannelValues = data.Where(d => channels.Contains(d.ChannelName)).Select(d => d.ChannelValue).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that error is because `allChannelValues` is of type `string`, whereas the `from x in data ...` expression you are attempting to assign to `allChannelValues` results in an `IEnumerable<ChannelValueType>`, where `ChannelValueType` is the same type as `x.ChannelValue`.  As the error states, an `IEnumerable<ChannelValueType>` cannot be implicitly converted to `string` to store in `allChannelValues`.

The other answers provide a more efficient way to do this, but just to "finish the thought" of what you had started to do...

```
List<string> channels = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ModbusChannels)).ToList();
IEnumerable<ChannelValueType> allChannelValues = Enumerable.Empty<ChannelValueType>();

foreach (string item in channels)
{
    IEnumerable<ChannelValueType> channelValues = from x in data
                                                  where x.ChannelName.Contains(item)
                                                  select x.ChannelValue;

    allChannelValues = allChannelValues.Concat(channelValues);
}

string allChannelValuesText = string.Join(", ", allChannelValues);
```

Declaring `allChannelValues` with the appropriate type is all that is needed to eliminate the error.

You were also assigning `allChannelValues` on every iteration of the `foreach`, so at the completion of the loop `allChannelValues` would contain the result of only the last iteration.  Instead, we store the query results in `channelValues` and then concatenate that to `allChannelValues` to save the cumulative results of the loop; `allChannelValues` is initialized with an [empty enumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.empty) so there is something on which to call [`.Concat()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat) on the first iteration.

Finally, we use [`string.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.join#System_String_Join__1_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) to build a comma-separated `string` of the resulting `ChannelValue` values.  It is not until this line is executed that the LINQ queries/methods in the `foreach` block are actually evaluated, but that does not affect the result.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you have taken to explain it.